# Low-level C I/O: When read from one file and write to another I'm hitting an infinite loop

Tags: c, io, low-level-io

I am working on an assignment that only allows use of low-level I/O (read(), write(), lseek()) as well as perror().

I have been able to open the nessisary in and out files with correct permissions, but when I output I get an infinite loop of the in file contents to out. See snippet below...

```
void *buf = malloc(1024);
while((n = read(in, buf, 1024)) > 0){
    if(lseek(in, n, SEEK_CUR) == -1){
        perror("in file not seekable");
        exit(-1);
    }
    while((m = write(out, buf, n)) > 0){
        if(lseek(out, m, SEEK_CUR) == -1){
            perror("out file not seekable");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    if(m == -1){ perror("error writing out"); exit(-1); }
}
if(n == -1){ perror("error reading in"); exit(-1); }
```

I have removed some error trapping from my code and you can assume the variables are initialized and includes statements are there.

Comment: What debugging have you done so far?  For instance, which loop is it stuck in, the outer loop or the inner loop?

Comment: I think what you are doing is writing the same line repetitively. Try changing the `while` around `write` to an `if`

Comment: It's stuck in the inner loop. Beyond that, I can't tell you much else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is the inner loop:

```
while((m = write(out, buf, n)) > 0){
```

should really be

```
if((m = write(out, buf, n)) > 0){
```

You only want `buf` to be written once, not infinitely many times.  What you also need to handle is short writes, that is, when write returns with m < n && m > 0.

Also, the `lseek()` calls are wrong, but they don't lead to the loop. `read()` and `write()` already advance the current file offset.  You do not need to manually advance it, unless you want to skip bytes in the input or output file (note that in the output file case, on UNIX, skipping bytes may lead to so-called "holes" in files, regions which are zero but don't occupy disk space).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you seeking on the input file after your read? Since you will, at most, read 1024 bytes (meaning `n` will be somewhere between 0 and 1024), you will be continuously seeking to somewhere beyond where you've left the input file pointer so that you'll *lose* data in the transfer (including probably beyond the end of the file when you get near the end).

This *may* be one cause why you have an infinite loop but the far more insidious one is the use of `while` for the write. Since this will return values greater than zero on success, you will continuously write the first chunk to the file over and over. At least until you run out of disk space or other resources.

You also don't need the `seek` on the write either. The `read` and `write` calls do what they have to do *and* advance the file pointer correctly for the next `read` or `write` - it's not something you have to do manually.

You can probably simplify the whole thing to:

```
while ((n = read (in, buf, 1024)) > 0) {
    if ((m = write (out, buf, n)) != n) {
        perror ("error writing out");
        exit (-1);
    }
}
```

which has the advantages of:

- getting rid of the `seek` calls;
- removing the 'infinite' loop;
- checking that you've written *all* the bytes requested.

Comment: Wouldn't lseek increment the current location in the file by n, given the whence value of SEEK_CUR?

Comment: Exactly, which is why the lseek() calls don't cause the loop, they only cause skipped bytes.